# Почему импортированная функция возвращает None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть такова - есть проект с папкой dictionary - в ней много скрипов с модулями
Рабочий скрипт находится в той же директории, где и dictionary.

Чтобы импортировать модули, использовал:

```
name = 'Dictionary'
sys.path.append(name) 
for i in os.listdir(name):  
    if i.endswith('.py'):
         i2=i.split('.')[0]
         exec('import '+i2) 
         proc = exec(i2+'.RUS("'+text+'")')
```

RUS - имеет в конце return (text)  и нареканий не вызывает

Но в proc почему-то попадает None

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы импортировать модуль по имени, можно воспользоваться функцией 
`import_module` из модуля `importlib`.

Пример использования:

```
from importlib import import_module
sys = import_module('sys')  # Примерно соответствует import sys
```

Дальше импортированный таким образом модуль можно использовать точно так же как если бы он был импортирован стандартным образом через `import`.

В вашем случае, насколько я понимаю, нужно импортировать модуль и вызвать функцию `RUS` из этого модуля с параметром `text`. Сделать это можно так:

```
module = import_module(i.split('.')[0])
result = module.RUS(text)
```

По поводу того, что "proc всегда возвращает None " - на самом деле в переменную proc попадает не результат выполнения импортированной функции, а результат выполнения функции `exec`, которая ничего не возвращает. Здесь по идее можно заменить `exec` на `eval`, но вообще я не рекомендовал бы использовать ни то ни другое: например, если значение в переменную `text` попадает откуда-то извне программы, то можно туда положить специально подготовленную строку (например `'")\nprint("Hello!'`), и тогда команда `proc = exec(i2+'.RUS("'+text+'")')` сделает немного не то, что вы ожидаете.

Импортирование модуля, как я показал выше, намного безопаснее, чем использование `exec` и `eval`.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало)